# How to find a server's IP address on DreamHost?

Tags: hosting, ip, dreamhost

I have a main domain registered and hosted with Godaddy. Let's call it example.com

I'd like to point the subdomain foo.example.com to a server I have with Dreamhost.
It's in my understanding I have to set up an A Record to point to the IP address of the Dreamhost server.

How do I find out that IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your domains list on Dreamhost, there is a 'DNS' link just below each [domain] that you have. This links to a page that displays Non-editable DreamHost DNS records for [domain].
Use the A record from there.

Comment: You can also run 'dig mysubdomain.example.com @ns1.dreamhost.com' from a Linux command shell. Oh and also, you could just set the Dreamhost nameservers to be responsible for that subdomain by adding the correct ns records (subdomain.example.com IN NS ns1.dreamhost.com) - that way you avoid the problems caused by Dreamhost changing your ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Useless.

Dont get me wrong - this is actually trivial ("ping yourdomain.com" will show you).

But pointing your subdomain IN A record to this wont help...
...until you register the subdomain with Dreamhost in their control panel somewhere. Because their web server only forwards those request to you that match your domains.

Reason? Having many websites on one ip address - which is standard and required for shared hosting providers. Make sure you have that under control.

Then, basically open a command line and type

Ping Wahteveryourdomain.com

(like: ping www.servervault.com)

and you see the IP address.

Comment: I think I might need to clarify my question. My domain is hosted by Godaddy. The main site files are hosted at Godaddy. I need to create an A record at Godaddy to point to the Dreamhost servers. How do I find out the IP for the Dreamhost server? Thanks

Comment: Ask dreamhost support ;)